# Binding Data List of ListView or 2D array

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-mvc

Im tried to Bind data to HTML from List of Listview<> like this

Controller code

```
namespace Cashiering_system.Areas.MainPage.Controllers
{
    [Area("MainPage")] // THIS IS REAL SHIT .... F$#$
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult MainPageLayout()
        {
            DatabaseOperation dbo = new DatabaseOperation();
            ViewBag.ListOfData = dbo.Read("Select * from database", 1 ,"MainController");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

and Read method is

```
public List<List<string>> Read(string SQL, int column_no, string Function)
        {
            List<List<string>> outterlist = new List<List<string>>();
            
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQL, conn);
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                List<string> innserlist = new List<string>();
                for (short i = 0; i < column_no; i++){
                    innserlist.Add(rdr[i].ToString());
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loop: " + i + " Data :" + rdr[i].ToString());
                }
                outterlist.Add(innserlist);
                rdr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                innserlist.Add("Error Display data from, Function: " + Function);
                outterlist.Add(innserlist);

            }
            conn.Close();
            return outterlist;
        }
```

Then i did not find any solution
but i solved this problem for any one looking for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this in your View

```
@{
    List<List<string>> data = ViewBag.ListOfData;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].Count; j++){
            <a>@data[i][j]</a>
        }
    }
 }
```

It works fine with me if there are any enhancement please share it to us